# What is the problem with the merge shapefiles tool in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector, merge

I'm having trouble merging shapefiles in QGIS. I'm using plugin ftools 0.6.1 and I get this:

[image]

Any workarounds someone may know of?

Comment: Use QGSI latest release 1.7.4

Comment: I am using it already.

Comment: Did you every figure out the problem? I seem to be getting the same error, but I'n not sure why. I'm essentially merging buffer layers, so I'm not sure what the issue would be.

Answer (score 2):

There is a considerable difference between the core plugin, fTools, in version 1.7.4 and latest (1.8 RC, or 1.9 master branch). I'm guessing the new version is not quite ready for release, as its __init__.py file has not been updated beyond the same 0.6.1 version.

However, I was able to do a quick fix to get this function of the plugin to work in 1.7.4. Open the noted file that exhibits the error in a good text editor (BBEdit or TextWrangler on Mac). Here is where it is located...

```
On Win: [drive letter]:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\python\plugins\fTools\tools\doMergeShapes.py

On Mac: /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins/fTools/tools/doMergeShapes.py
```

You will generally need to make the file write-able and authenticate when saving on Mac, as the core files are usually owned by a different user.

The error references line 124:

> if self.inEncoding == None:
>   AttributeError: 'Dialog' object has no attribute 'inEncoding'

This means that *self.inEncoding* has not yet been defined as an instance attribute, but is being tested against None. Merely adding an assignment for *self.inEncoding* in the Dialog's __init__ method allows the plugin to work. Add a new line below line 22, so that line 22 and 23 look like this:

```
self.outFileName = None
self.inEncoding = None  # added this line
```

This allows the plugin to work, but the 1.8 RC version has 23 changes over the 1.7.4 version in this file alone. So, it could be the new version also fixes some other issues.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to merge my buffers without the error you mentioned by using QGIS 1.9.90-Alpha (Code revision 20e5f5a). That doesn't solve the problem, but it does circumvent it. Once I was done, I just added the shape file in QGIS 1.7.4

Answer (score 0):

Check the Shapes Encoding. What is the origin of those shape files? maybe it were generated by a messy application.

Comment: The shapefiles are ok.

Comment: with that similar error, I changed the Encoding for all files (Properties > General > Provider-Specific Options > Encoding) from System to UTF-8 (which matched other layers in my map). Still got the same error.